# Best way to `tee` to stdout and to a process

Tags: bash, stdout, tee

I want to do something like this:

```
echo 'foo' | tee /dev/stdout > >(cat)
```

where the stdout from `echo` gets sent to the terminal and to the cat process.  Is there a simpler way to do this?

When I run this:

```
 echo 'foo' | tee >(echo 'bar')
```

for some reason, it does not echo 'foo' it only echoes 'bar', why?

Comment: `echo 'foo' | tee >(echo 'bar')` prints `bar` and `foo` for me.

Comment: that's so weird b/c it doesn't for me, I am on MacOS, maybe tee is different here

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It's absolutely pointless to argue about that; it's all about the order in which the `echo foo`, `echo bar` and `tee` commands will be started and finished, and that's _unpredictable_.  If `echo bar` finishes before `tee` tries to write anything into its pipe, `tee` will be killed by a `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: thanks for the insights, ultimately my goal is to tee to a process and stdout, how do I do so?

Comment: You do it _exactly the way that you have shown_, but the command in the process substitution should read what's written to it, or it may terminate too early.

Comment: `echo foo | tee >(echo bar; cat >/dev/null)` in your second example

Comment: @UncleBilly I did not argue, I stated.

Comment: I am not arguing that I would like an upvote, I am just saying that this question is not worthy of an upvote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do it exactly the way you have shown:

```
somecommand | tee >(othercommand)
```

The output of `somecommand` would be written to the input of `othercommand` and to standard output.

The issue with your `echo 'bar'` process substitution is that it doesn't care about the input that comes via `tee` from `echo 'foo'`, so it just outputs `bar` as quickly as it can and terminates.  The `tee` utility then tries to write to it, but fails and therefore terminates (from receiving a `PIPE` signal) before it writes the string to standard output.  Or, `tee` may have time to write the data to the process substitution, in which case both `bar` and `foo` would be printed on standard output, it's not deterministic.

You need to make sure that the command in the process substitution actually reads the data sent to it (otherwise, what would be the point of sending it data?)  [As Uncle Billy suggests in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/542522/best-way-to-tee-to-stdout-and-to-a-process/542526#comment1005911_542522), this is easily arranged in your example by letting the process substitution simply use `cat >/dev/null` (assuming you're not interested in the data coming from `tee`):

```
echo 'foo' | tee >(cat >/dev/null; echo 'bar')
```

or

```
echo 'foo' | tee >(echo 'bar'; cat >/dev/null)
```

(these two variations would vary only in the order of the final output of the two strings)

Comment: `somecommand | tee >(othercommand); cmd3` is problematic in several shell implementations including `bash` in that `othercommand` is not _waited for_, so its output may come after the output of `cmd3` for instance. `{ cmd1 3>&- | tee /dev/fd/4 4>&1 >&3 3>&- | cmd2 3>&-; } 3>&1` would not have the problem and would work with POSIX sh on systems with /dev/fd/x

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer wasn't very clear to me, as the result is piped to `/dev/null`, obscuring if the pipe worked.

To practice confirming the value is passed, you can `cat` or use `tr` on the piped value like this:

```
% echo foo | tee >(tr -d '\n') ; echo bar
foo
foobar
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, all you’ve done here is provide an example (and not a very good one) of the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo 'foo' | tee /dev/tty |other-program
```

Comment: That would not really put `foo` on standard output though.

Comment: yeah and not always looking for /dev/tty, just to stdout, whatever it may be

Comment: It does. Test it: `echo 'foo' | tee /dev/tty |wc`

Comment: Try putting your command in a script,  and then running the script with stdout redirected.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood the OP.

Comment: "It does." Not really: `echo 'foo' | tee /dev/tty |wc > x.txt` would write "`foo`" to the console and "`1 1 4`" to the file `x.txt`. If I understood the question correctly, the OP searches for a solution that writes "`foo 1 1 4`" to the file `x.txt`.